# MATLAB loop refactoring

Tags: matlab

I'm curious to know if there is a better way to express the following loop:

```
To = 1;
fileName = "fourier/signal.txt";
spectrum_left(abs(spectrum_left) < 1e-3) = 0+0i;
Ts = 1 / Fs;
t = 0:Ts:To-Ts;
signal = load(fileName, "-ascii");
Ns = numel(signal);
Fs = Ns / To;

fr = f(abs(spectrum_left) > 0)
a = abs(spectrum_left(abs(spectrum_left) > 0))
p = angle(spectrum_left(abs(spectrum_left) > 0))

signal_synth = 0;
len = length(a);

for i=1:len
    a_i = a(i);
    p_i = p(i);
    f_i = fr(i);
    s_i = a_i * cos(2*pi*f_i*t + p_i)
    signal_synth = signal_synth + s_i;
end
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. And Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB, [element-wise operators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html), that preceded by the period character `(.)`, can be applied on arrays. I used `(:)` operator to convert the vectors to column vectors. Note that `t` is a row vector, when it is combined with column vectors the result will be a matrix that is formed by implicit expansion. In order to sum up the values the function [sum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) is used that by default sums along the first dimension of the matrix and the result will be a row vector with the same size as `t`.

```
signal_synth = sum(a(:) .* cos(2 * pi * f(:) .* t + p(:)));
```

A more compact form using matrix multiplication:

```
signal_synth = a(:).' * cos(2 * pi * f(:) .* t + p(:));
```